# ATI HD 6320 ASUS Brightness doesn't change

Tags: 12.10, grub2, ati, brightness, asus

When i press Function + [F5 or F6] to increase or decrease the brightness,
the adjustment display on top right pops out and the slider moves but the screen brightness remains the same.
i've done various changes to the grub file such as
changing the value

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

or

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

or

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

or

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux"
```

**sudo update-grub** to each of them and reboot. Still none of them works.

I've also tried changing the value manually using the method:

```
cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

it gave me the output value 50,
tried lower it down to 2 with:

```
echo 2 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

still, nothing changed. the brightness remain the same

Help is very much appreciated.

```
fglrxinfo
display: :0.0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 6320 Graphics
OpenGL version string: 4.2.12172 Compatibility Profile Context 12.10.17
```